# Keycloak cannot identify clientAuthenticator from the configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I am trying to connect keycloak client to spring boot project but I do not known how to solve this issue although I daily search the solution for handling this error. Can anyone help me?

**Application property**

```
keycloak.enabled=true
keycloak.realm=master
keycloak.auth-server-url= http://localhost:8090/auth/
keycloak.resource=admin-cli
keycloak.confidential-port=0
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.verify-token-audience=true
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
keycloak.credentials.secret=ceK01wMKEQ6WoeBAy61PvTLzbt5iAebt
keycloak.credentials.username=root
keycloak.credentials.password=admin
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
keycloak.bearer-only               =true
```

**Keycloak Configuration**

```
@Value("${keycloak.credentials.secret}}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Value("${keycloak.resource}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${keycloak.auth-server-url}")
    private String authUrl;

    @Value("${keycloak.realm}")
    private String realm;

    @Value("${keycloak.credentials.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${keycloak.credentials.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public Keycloak initKeycloak(){
        return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .serverUrl(authUrl)
                .realm(realm)
                .username(username)
                .password(password)
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(secretKey)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin*")
                .hasRole("admin")
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
    }

    public SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthority(){
        SimpleAuthorityMapper mapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        mapper.setConvertToUpperCase(true);
        return mapper;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthority());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver(){
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter> keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean<KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter> keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean<KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }
```

**Localhost Error**

*When I access localhost:8080, it shows below*

> Type Exception Report
>
> Message Can't identify clientAuthenticator from the configuration of
> client 'admin-cli' . Check your adapter configurations
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that
> prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't identify clientAuthenticator from
> the configuration of client 'admin-cli' . Check your adapter
> configurations
> org.keycloak.adapters.authentication.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils.bootstrapClientAuthenticator(ClientCredentialsProviderUtils.java:54)
> org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.internalBuild(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:99)
> org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:202)
> org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.resolve(KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.java:41)
> org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.resolve(KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.java:40)
> org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext.resolveDeployment(AdapterDeploymentContext.java:89)
> org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler.preflightCors(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:100)
> org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler.handleRequest(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:75)
> org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:177)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
>
> Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server
> logs.

**Keycloak**

*My keycloak url: localhost:8090/auth*

[Keycloak image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMLew.png)

Answer (score 3):

Add this property :

```
keycloak.credentials.provider=secret
```

Comment: Ok, thank for your help. I have solved this issue recently.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `AuthzClient` object and your client credentials have changed, you'll need to update your code accordingly. Here's how you can do it:

```java
Map<String, Object> clientCredentials = new HashMap<>();
clientCredentials.put("secret", clientSecret);
clientCredentials.put("provider", "secret");
```